# Replacing carriage returns (?) after compiling HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

After parsing HTML I get the following object:

[image: parsed HTML]

I would like to strip all the "↵" except of one. How can I do this? I tried with something like this:

```
weirdString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
```

However, this replaces all the "↵" but as I've already mentioned I want to replace all of those except the first...

Comment: A more difficult query by me: My wished result would be the following:
↵ 1. ↵ Eine Anmeldung ist innerhalb ....

So: IF there are multiple ↵ in a row (seperated by whitespace(?)), remove all ↵ but the first + its whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture it and restore with a backreference:

```
weirdString.replace(/^([^\S\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n))|(?:\r\n?|\n)/g, "$1"));
```

No need using `m` modifier here.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `([^\S\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n))` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^\S\r\n]*` - any 0+ whitespaces other than CR and LF
  - `(?:\r\n?|\n)`  -  any style line break
- `|` - or
- `(?:\r\n?|\n)` - any style line break.

With `$1`, only the contents captured into Group 1 are put back in the replacement result.

```js
var weirdString = "    \r\n\r\n\n\rSome text";
console.log(weirdString.replace(/^([^\S\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n))|(?:\r\n?|\n)/g, "$1"));
```

Comment: @S.Serp: `\S` matches a non-whitespace symbol. `[^\S]` = `\s`, it matches a whitespace symbol. `[^\S\r\n]` matches any symbol other than a non-whitespace, other than CR and other than LF.

Comment: I accept this answer since it clearly solves the question. However (as I commented in the intro post):
My wished result would be the following: ↵ 1. ↵ Eine Anmeldung ist innerhalb .... 
So: IF there are multiple ↵ in a row (seperated by whitespace(?)), remove all ↵ but the first + its whitespace
I can ask this as a new question + link it to this one if desired.

Comment: Wait, let me understand this comment

Comment: Looks like you want [`.replace(/^([^\S\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n))\s*/, "$1")`](https://jsfiddle.net/cLvpubvk/). Please let me know so that I could adjust the answer.

Comment: Now it's like this:
11:  ↵                         1.    Eine Anmeldung ist innerhalb ....  2.     Lorem ipsum

But I would like it to be like:
11: ↵ 1. ↵ Eine Anmeldung ist innerhalb .... ↵  2. ↵ Lorem ipsum

So only remove the ↵ + whitespace if there are multiple ↵ following each other but keeping all the single ones...

Comment: It is clearer now, but it would be much easier if you provided exact *string literal* to test against :(

Comment: Please do not log a new question for the same task. I will help here in the comments, if anything does not work as expected, and the best way to talk is via chat and using JSFiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

A little bit tricky, but why dont you first replace your first carriage return with something else? e.g.: %@% or something else, what your are not using in your text... then replace all other carriage returns, and at last return your %@% tag back to carrige return...

Answer (score 0):

The exact matching regexp must cope with some things you have not accounted for:

- first is whitespace that can be in between two such line ends.  It should be considered the case of intervening.
- Second is that the `\r` in front of `\n` should be considered optional, as it appears in texts that come from socket connections from internet (most protocols force to send `\r\n` but can be optional.
- a sequence of two or more newlines of this type should be collapsed to one `\n`  (or one `\r\n` as you prefer)

If you do a pattern match and substitute with multiple flag enabled you'll get the desired effect with this pattern:

```
([ \t]*\r*\n)+
```

as seen in the following [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LJOoTj/3).  I have substituted the newlines by a `[<--']\r\n` to be able to see the effect.  It also deletes all trailing whitespace at line ends (normally invisible) but doesn't touch the leading at beginning of lines (this could affect the visible looking of your text)